# Subjunctives and "am"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Hopefully this one is nice and simple. Which is correct:

> I would never say that I **am** superior to a cleaner.

or

> I would never say that I **were** superior to a cleaner.

I'm rather confused -- any answers (and an explanation of the answer) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is correct. The second is not.

You **could** substitute *was* for *were* and it would be OK:

- *I would never say that I **was** superior to a cleaner.*

That's just the ordinary past tense, echoing the morphological past of *would*. If you used *will* instead of *would*, *was* refers to your purported past superiority, while the present *am* is simply generic:

- *I will never say that I **was** superior to a cleaner.*
- *I will never say that I **am** superior to a cleaner.*

The reason is that the sogenannte "Subjunctive" is rare in English, and occurs only after certain predicates, of which *say* is not one, even in a universal temporal negative construction (i.e, *never say*).

In general, it's best to avoid mentioning the term ***"Subjunctive"*** when speaking of English grammar; it simply confuses people because they don't know what it means, either.

Comment: Thanks John. My instinct was that the first one was correct, but many (including an ex-teacher) argued that it was the other.

Comment: And that is exactly why John's last point is good advice. On occasion I have found - even on this site - people talking about "subjunctive" to mean "sentence which in some other languages would be expressed by a subjunctive". This is generally Not a Good Thing.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is the correct thing to say.

The Past Subjunctive, also called **unreal Past**, is used to express a wish that is unlikely to be fulfilled:

*I wish that he **were** here now.* (He can't be here despite my wishes.)

OR *It is high time we **moved** house*. (I don't think we can do this now.)

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/61963/2085).