# Why do we say "It's time we ate" and not "It's time we eat"?

Tags: grammar, future, simple-past

Why do we use the simple past but not the present or future in the following expressions:

> Don't you think it's time we went a little further
>
> Don't you think it's time we ate
>
> Don't you think it's time we went home

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an example of the [past subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Past_subjunctive):

> **Past subjunctive**
>
> Like the term *present subjunctive*, *past subjunctive* can be misunderstood, as it describes a *form* rather than a *meaning*. The past subjunctive is so named because it resembles the past indicative in form, but the difference between them is a difference in modality, not in temporality. For example, in *If that **were** true, I would know it*, the word *were* (a past subjunctive) has no past-tense sense and instead describes a counterfactual condition in the present.
>
> In addition to appearing in counterfactual *if* clauses (*If I were there, he would know it*), the past subjunctive form also appears in that clauses expressing a wish that is unlikely to be fulfilled. Usually the main-clause verb in this circumstance is *wish*, as in *I **wish** that he **were** here now*; but occasionally some other expression implying an unlikely wish is seen, as in *It **is high time** (that) he **bought** a new car* or *I **would rather** that he **did** that*. (The latter example can also be recast in the present subjunctive, expressing doubt but not as much doubt as the past subjunctive: *I **would rather** that he do that*).

Your examples are correct, and replacing them with simple present tense verbs wouldn't be standard usage.

To give the issue an extra spin, the article goes on to say that the present tense is also valid, with a slight twist in meaning:

> In contrast, hoped-for things that may possibly occur take the indicative. In this circumstance, often the main clause verb is *hope*, as in *I **hope** that he **comes** now*. Likewise, in *It **is high time** (that) he **buys** a new car*, there is a real possibility that he will indeed do so.

FumbleFingers, in the comments below, questions the validity of the present tense construction.  The outcome of our discussion (such as it was) was that it appears to be significantly less common (therefore either newfangled, dialectical, or both), and it is dubious whether most people would accept it.  So my best advice is to take that paragraph with a grain of salt, and use the past tense if you want to use this type of construction.

Comment: I can't agree your last paragraph. Introducing the word *"high"* doesn't change anything. The standard idiomatic usage of *It's time [pronoun] [verb]* always puts *[verb]* in the past tense (presumably because [verb] *should already have been **done*** at the time of speaking).

Comment: Well, if you notice, *"high"* was in the middle paragraph too; it wasn't introduced in the third.  You can remove *high* and the point would be the same.  Past that, are you saying that *It's time [noun] [present tense verb]* is incorrect?

Comment: I guess I'd better think a bit more before nailing my colours too firmly to the mast, but my gut feel is *"It's time he buys a new car"* is **not** acceptable, and I can't yet think of any variation on it that would be. Maybe it's a dialectal usage?

Comment: It could be.  Google has 157 results for *about time he comes* and 401 for *about time he came*.  Not that it proves much, but at least it's in use somewhere and for some reason.

Comment: GB has [11 results for "it's time he goes"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it%27s+time+he+goes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22it%27s+time+he+goes%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=2EZrT6HpJ5Kq8QO_5KXrBg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3a14aea1404f94da&biw=1290&bih=902), against [31,000 for "it's time he went"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it%27s+time+he+went%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I stand my ground.

Comment: BTW, that's 225 results, not 31,000.  And [google.com](https://www.google.com/#q=%22it%27s+time+he+went%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&psj=1&ei=RkhrT5vPGYns0gGCnenBBg&start=332&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f2a63d061d7abea&biw=1366&bih=643) shows 198 vs. 342, a much closer ratio.

Comment: ...even more extreme, Google Books has **four** instances of *"about time he comes"*, two of which are duplicates, and one is an accidental collocation across two sentences. On the other hand, it says there are **About 278,000 results** for *"about time he came"*. I'm definitely standing pat - no "dialectal usage" is going to wash with me.

Comment: Which is actually [144 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22about+time+he+came%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22about+time+he+came%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=tkhrT5b6GIGftweU0vG2Bg&start=160&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=63a84ff2387071ab&biw=1366&bih=643).  Not sure why Google feels the need to multiply the number by 1000 before showing it to us.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2868/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-daniel-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers There.  Check my edit.  I'm still leaving room for the present tense (just in case) while stating the fact that is isn't standard and the OP should avoid it.

Comment: "Your examples are correct, and replacing them with simple present tense verbs wouldn't be standard usage." Can you provide a citation? I'm not convinced this is true.

Comment: The Wikipedia article establishes that the examples are correct, and researching occurrences of the present tense variation reveals that it is vastly outnumbered by the past tense.  The corpuses to which I have access bear that out to my satisfaction.  That's as to whether it's standard.  I'm not sure about the grammaticality.  I'd be inclined to think that it is grammatical, but it would take a greater analyst than I to prove it to any comprehensive degree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Would this be considered grammatically correct: "Don't you think it's time **to be going** home?"? I'm asking because that is how I would say it, but maybe it's  L2 interference.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: There's nothing wrong with that, or indeed with *"It's time **to go** home!"*, but they're not the usage under discussion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your quick reply, but if the question is asking "why" we say **we went** and not **we go** could it not mean the OP was unaware of alternative phrasings? Is there a difference in meaning between the three forms?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think the reason why idiomatically we use past rather than present subjunctive here is subtle and idiomatic. But I don't see OP as asking for alternative phrasings (this is ELU, not ELL). Any differences in meaning will also be subtle, idiomatic, and not universally recognised consistently.

Comment: Searching Google books before 1800, then the construction was usually *it's time I tell you* or *it's time I should tell you*. I believe the first should be interpreted as the present subjunctive and the second as the *should*-subjunctive, where *should* is the subjunctive of *shall*, and an indication of future action. The only time the past subjunctive was used was when the action was viewed as unlikely.  For example: *'tis time he were hanged, indeed, for I know no other amends he can make us.*

Answer (score -3):

For all three examples, the present sounds perfectly fine:

> Don't you think it's time we go a little further?
>
> It's time we eat.
>
> Don't you think it's time we go home?

and they have pretty much the same meaning as your given sentences. The future is not allowed:

> *It's time we will eat.

Also, the present progressive doesn't work:

> *It's time we are eating.

This gives evidence that the first alternative given 'It's time we ate' is not really the past but is more likely a vestigial **past subjunctive** form.

Comment: I don't agree; the present doesn't sound quite right here.

Comment: Here's [support](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/linguistics/3435001-its_time_we_should_go_home.html) and [other support](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2013480).

Comment: I think this is a regionalism.  I would never use the present in any of these sentences; I believe many people would find it ungrammatical to do so; but I'm sure there are places where this usage is quite acceptable.