# Dumbledore's note for Harry or question about sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

When I was re-watching the well-known movie about the boy who lived I noticed that the tenses in the note from Dumbledore (spoiler, sorry ><) don't really correspond, or do they?

Here's what I mean:

> It **is** time it **was** returned to you.

Shouldn't it be:

> It **is** time it **is** returned to you.

Of course, Dumbledore is not dumb (or movie creators, if you will :P), and I'm just wrong, but could you explain why?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of at least 3 questions, some others of which should be closed.

Comment: @PeterShor thank you! I searched using "sequence-of-tenses" hashtag, that's why I couldn't find that question.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/61963.